# How to fix auto complete field position?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete, kendo-ui, position

I am using Kendo UI controls in my MVC4 application.There is one section in application which contains two parts. Below is the image of those two parts:-

[image]

As you can see that there are two parts A and B. Both parts contains the ZIP Code field. ZIP code field is auto complete field. So when I put input in section B's ZIP Code field the auto complete is opening in section A's ZIP Code.

I have tried to fix its position but it's not working.Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Can you please provide us the code so we can check? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per screenshot I am understand that you are adding the UI dynamically. So, you have to set the ID of each control dynamically.

The issue is raised because of both the Autocomplete control have same ID. Please set the different ID for both the controls and check it.

If still issue not solved then please provide your code.